# Can we have more than one theme in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

My website is almost ready but now I want to change its design completely. If I installed and use new theme, can I have all the features and functionality same as previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the actual theme and functionality.

The theme will have to support the same features and functionality.

If you are just using the built in functionality or are only using extensions as a means of adding features, you should be able to switch templates relatively easy.

If you build custom features, you will have to re-integrate all your custom functionality.

Since I do not know what kind of features and functionality you are referring to, I will not be able to give you a more complete answer, but the above information should help you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your cooperation !!